# Composite of Continuous Real Functions at Point -- not necessarily continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let us recall the definition of continuity of a real function at a point.

$f(x)$ is continuous at $a$ iff:

$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R_{>0}: \forall \delta \in \mathbb R_{>0}: \forall x \in \mathbb R: |x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$

Let $f(x)$ denote the function:

$\forall x \in \mathbb R: f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & : x \text { irrational} \\ \dfrac 1 q & : x = \dfrac p q: p, q \in \mathbb Z, q > 0, \gcd (p, q) = 1 \end{cases}$

This is Thomae's function, and is well-known for its pathological property of being continuous at all $x$ irrational but discontinuous at all $x$ rational.

Let $g(x)$ denote the function:

$\forall x \in \mathbb R: g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & : x \le 0 \\ 1 & : x > 0 \end{cases}$

This is continuous everywhere except where $x = 0$.

Now consider the function:

$\forall x \in \mathbb R: h(x) = g(f(x))$

If you work this out, you establish that $h(x)$ is the function defined as:

$\forall x \in \mathbb R: h(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & : x \text { irrational} \\ 1 & : x \text { rational} \end{cases}$

which is also a famous pathological function: it is a Dirichlet function, which has the delightful property of being discontinuous *everywhere*.

Hence we have the composite of 2 functions, each of which is continuous at certain points (i.e. irrationals for $f$, non-zero for $g$) but itself is not continuous anywhere.

But then, you turn the page in your Topology textbook (in this case "Introduction to Metric and Topological Spaces" by W.A. Sutherland), and you read:

"If $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ are topological spaces, and $f: T_1 \to T_2$, $g: T_2 \to T_3$ are continuous mappings, then $g \circ f: T_1 \to T_3$."

The language of continuity is defined in topology in terms of inverse mappings on open sets:

$\forall U \in \tau_2: f^{-1} [U] \in \tau_1$

where $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are the topologies of $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively.

Now there does exist a definition of continuity at a point in the topological context:

The mapping $f$ is continuous at $x$ (with respect to the topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$) iff:

for *every* neighborhood $N$ of $f(x)$ in $T_2$, there exists a neighborhood $M$ of $x$ in $T_1$ such that $f [M] \subseteq N$.

And in this context, the continuity or not of a composite function at a point is not well explored. It *seems* to be taken for granted that the composite of two continuous functions at a point is itself composite, but (as seen in the specific instance of Thomae's function) this is *specifically contradicted* by certain pathological examples.

(You can see how this applies to the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity on Thomae's function: the closer you get to an irrational number, the larger and larger get the denominators of the rational numbers near it, hence the smaller and smaller get the images of those rational numbers. So you have an open set around an irrational $c$, say, which is a teeny-tiny open real interval containing rational numbers with large denominators, which is the preimage of another teeny-tiny open real interval containing reciprocals of those large denominators, and so the topological definition of a continuous mapping applies.)

When you map this image interval, containing $0$ and $+$ve rationals in it, to $\mathbb R$ using $g$, the subsequent image is $\{0, 1\}$. Going back the other way, I am having difficulty interpreting the "neighbourhood" definition of continuity in order to investigate the reason why the continuity of a composite function at a point in a general topological space.

Can somebody help me through this? I need to be guided through the exploration of continuity of the composite of mappings which are continuous at a point ''from the topological perspective''.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $a$, $f(a)=b$, $g$ is continuous at $b$, then $g\circ f$ is continuous at $a$.  In your example, there are no cases where continuity of $f$ at $a$ and continuity of $g$ at $f(a)$ both hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following result: Let $f : T_1 \to T_2, g: T_2 \to T_3$. If $f$ is continuous at $x \in T_1$ and $g$ is **matchingly continuous at $f(x) \in T_2$**, then $g \circ f : T_1 \to T_3$ is continuous at $x \in T_1$.

The problem with your $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, Thomae's function and $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, the step function at $0$, is that the continuities don't match as above. More specifically, $f$ is continuous at all irrational $j$. However, it maps those points to $0$: $f(j) = 0$, **precisely where $g$ fails to be continuous**. Thus, the result above does not allow you to conclude the continuity of $g \circ f$ at irrational $j$.

Comment: How obvious. Would this make a useful "Spot the silly mistake" question in a course on topology, any professional teachers out there?